# wps-grass-bridge misses essential GRASS tool

Tags: grass-gis, web-service, wps, pywps

I set up a Web Processing Service with 52°North and GRASS (using the wps-grass-bridge).
I get a similar result like in the online example here: [52°North WPS Demo](http://geoprocessing.demo.52north.org:8080/wps/WebProcessingService?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WPS&VERSION=1.0.0)
I assume it would be similar with PyWPS.

This is very nice. Now I would like to use i.cluster which needs to have the bands grouped in subgroups. In GRASS you would run i.group before running i.cluster. Unfortunately i.group is not available in any of the WPS. How can this be missing?

Does anybody have an idea how to make i.group available with the wps-grass-bridge? Or is there an alternative to i.group for defining groups on a raster dataset?

Comment: You could add the i.group functionality as a Python script: https://code.google.com/p/wps-grass-bridge/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpywps_services

Comment: I'd love to have i.group as a python script. Unfortunately the library does not list any imagery scripts. Any idea where I can get it from?

Comment: Here an example via GRASS Python scripting library: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#i.group_with_patterns_as_name_for_input